# quser does not exist on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

According to a couple of [articles](http://learningpcs.blogspot.ca/2009/11/utility-windows-7-quser.html) that i have found, the quser command should exist on Windows 7, however I have a system running Windows 7 Home Premium and the QUser command does not exist in C:\windows\system32. Is there any way I can get this executable added?

Answer (score 1):

Quser command is only available in W7 Pro or higher, not available in W7 Home.

Currently testing if you can copy "quser.exe" from pro to home and if it works. (copy to system32 folder)

Copied quser.exe from another Pro system but it errors out:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>quser /?
>
> {Message(): LoadString failed, Error 15105, (0x00003B01)}
>
> C:\Windows\system32>

quser.exe DLL dependencies are:

WINSTA.DLL

UTILDLL.DLL

USER32.DLL

KERNEL32.DLL

NTDLL.DLL

MSVCRT.DLL

which are present in the system32 folder.

Maybe someone else can tell us if this can be done in W7 Home.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to copy the quser.exe.mui file from the C:\Windows\System32\en-US folder to the same location. If you aren't using en-US as your primary locale, you will need to copy if from your current one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on software licensing but I'm guessing that any solution involving copying system files from a more expensive version of Windows lies somewhere between a violation of license terms and unsupported behavior that might break on any Windows update.

---

Instead, the [Cassia](https://github.com/danports/cassia#well-that-sounds-like-a-blast-so-how-do-i-use-it) project will likely solve your problem. It comes with a `SessionInfo.exe` application that has similar functionality to `quser.exe`, or you can use the library.