# How do I log off a user via command line in windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I would like to log off a specific local user using the command line in windows 8.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Use `QUERY USER` to get a list of logged on user sessions. Then use `LOGOFF #` (replacing # with the appropriate session ID seen in the previous command's output) to log off the user.

There might be a slightly more graceful way to do it in one line with PowerShell, but this should work all the way down to XP regardless. If UAC is enabled, you will need to run these commands from an elevated prompt.

Comment: I get this error: 'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you running? Might be a Pro+ feature. EDIT: Yup, looks like that's the problem. Tested good on Win7Ent and Win8Pro, but failed on Win7Home. Let's see what other options there are...

Comment: More confirmation that quser.exe (used by `QUERY USER`) isn't available in Home editions: http://superuser.com/q/508708/50086

Comment: Yup that's the problem.  The edition of windows was basic.

Answer (score 0):

As OP found, [`quser` isn't included in Home editions of Windows](https://superuser.com/q/508708/282374). But you can use the [Cassia](https://github.com/danports/cassia) project which has similar functionality.

If you [unzip the release](https://github.com/danports/cassia/releases/tag/2.0.0) and run:

```
Samples\SessionInfo\Source\SessionInfo\bin\Release\SessionInfo.exe listsessions $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

the output will include Session IDs and Users. Get the session ID for the user, then run as **admin**:

```
Samples\SessionInfo\Source\SessionInfo\bin\Release\SessionInfo.exe logoff $env:COMPUTERNAME 3
```

---

I wanted to automate this, so [I wrote a small program](https://github.com/darthwalsh/SignYouOut) using Cassia that loops through all sessions and signs off all other users.